# Python: повторять пока ошибка

Tags: python

Добрый день!

Хочу поинтересоваться, как будет правильно составить конструкцию на питоне, которая должна выполняться, пока результатом выполнения функции является ошибка? Думаю, что реализуется с помощью try except, а как именно - не знаю...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def foo():
  #smth
  raise Exception('Exception')

def main():
  while True:
    try:
      foo()
    except:
      print 'expected exception'
    else:
      #break loop
      break

main()
```